# What are the effects of accelerating a static/stationary electron in a vacuum

Tags: electrons, vacuum

The questions I ask are based on the peculiarities of quantum physics that I except but don't necessarily understand.

Thought experiment: If you are able to place a single static electron in a vacuum (ignoring the possible effects of virtual particles) with the understanding that there are virtual photons surrounding it (do not know if these are only present when the electron is in motion) how fast would the electron have to be accelerated to produce an electromagnetic field? Would an electromagnetic field be produced instantly at any velocity above 0? Second: When shown a typical stationary bar magnet with "particles" spread around it to help vizualize the magnetic field, once placed" do those "particles" remain influenced by the magnetic field?

Comment: Can you rephrase the second part of the question?

Comment: A perfectly static electron has no uncertainty in its position and no uncertainty in its momentum. The [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) forbids that. So if you insist that its momentum is very small (and hence the uncertainty in its momentum is also very small), you have to accept large uncertainty in its position.

Comment: If you would like to resubmit an answer please re-read the question. I didn't ask about the Heisenberg uncertainty principle and I didn't ask about momentum.

Comment: To S's Cat. You often see a horseshoe magnet or a bar magnet with Magnetic particle sprinkled around 2 show magnetic fiel

Comment: To S's Cat. You often see a horseshoe magnet or bar magnet with Magnetic particles sprinkled around to visually depict magnetic lines. One Source magnetic particles are placed are those particles still under the influence of the magnetic field? Meaning, I guess I can answer my own question, is a magnetic field always "on"? It's a question trying to figure out if the magnetic field is fluctuating even though the magnetic particles in the field or stationary?

Comment: I apologize I'm not spell checking.

Answer (score 0):

> Would an electromagnetic field be produced instantly at any velocity above 0?

Even a static electron produces an electric field. And an electron moving with a constant velocity also produces an electric field, along with a time-dependent magnetic field. Only when an electron attains a non-zero acceleration (however that may be), it starts radiating electromagnetic radiation and can produce a time-dependent magnetic field as well. In total, what we get is an electromagnetic field.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying that stationary electrons do not produce magnetic fields?

Comment: @GiorgioComitini Yes. You need steady currents to produce a magnetic field.

Comment: A single electron with non-zero constant velocity does produce a magnetic field (stationary electrons do produce magnetic fields). Before you modified your answer you said it doesn't. It's alright now.

Comment: However, note that the magnetic field produced by the stationary electron (as well as its electric field) is time-dependent: the time dependence is due to the change in the electron's position. It's not oscillatory, but still time-dependent.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini A single electron moving with a constant velocity constitutes a current. But a stationary charge does not. So a stationary charge \textbf{does not} produce a magnetic field.

Comment: A static charge does not produce a magnetic field. A stationary charge (where by stationary I mean that the derivative of its velocity is zero, i.e. that it is non-accelerating) does as long as its velocity is different from zero. Regardless of what we mean by "stationary", you're answer is still wrong in that it says that the magnetic field produced by a constant-velocity electron is time-independent.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini Well, okay, I understand your meaning of "stationary". And yes, it should be a time-dependent magnetic field. Typo, I guess. Didn't check the previous time. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I do understand that a static electron does have an EM field. Stated more succinctly is an EM current generated as soon as the electron is accelerated?

Comment: @Cooper A static electron only has an electric field. It has no magnetic field.

Comment: @Cooper And the EM waves are produced not instantly; there is a time lag due to the finite speed of light. So at a point r distance away from the accelerating charge, the EM wave arrives t=r/c seconds later.

Comment: Giorgio: you stated that a static charge does not produce a magnetic field but it does where it is non-accelerating unless it's velocity is different than zero. Could you reread rephrase that answer please? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Scat: I understand that a stationary electron has an electric charge but I thought it had to be in motion to actually produce an electromagnetic field.
What do you mean by a "time dependent" magnetic field?

Comment: @Cooper First of all, I comprehend "stationary" as static, something that is non-moving, at rest. This is as per Oxford Dictionary definition. Let me clear that first. And a static electron only has an electric field, but no magnetic field.

Comment: @Cooper Time-dependent means the field varies with time. And please go through my answer carefully. I hope all your doubts will be cleared.